# Why am I getting TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm playing around with loops and the like while trying to learn Python on my own. I found an old exercise to build a guessing game so I'm trying that:

```
hidden = random.randrange(1, 100)
print(hidden)

guess = int(input("Please enter your guess: "))

for guess in hidden:
    if guess == hidden:
        print("That\'s it!\n\n Congrats !") + quit()
    elif guess < hidden:
        print("Too low :(")
    else:
        print("Too high!")
```

However I keep getting `TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable`. Any suggestions? An in depth explanation would be welcome as I want to understand as much as possible.

Comment: Your issue is that you're doing `for guess in hidden`. Which iterates over `hidden`, but `hidden` is simply a number that can't be iterated over

Comment: Which means? (not being rude just have no idea how this works)

Comment: Also, completely not being rude, maybe you should try more basic exercises. It seems you are missing some fundemental syntactic rules and programming concepts

Comment: Anyway to try and help here: when doing `for guess in hidden`, this creates `guess` as the loop's variable that in each iteration of this `for` loop, gets the next value off of `hidden` in that case. The problem here is that `hidden` in a number. try the next code to play with and maybe that will help you understand: `l = [1, 2, 3]; for x in l: print(x)`

Comment: This was a culmination of the loops and integers tutorial I found, what do I need to look at to get a better understanding of it?

Comment: What is the purpose of your for loop? If the number does not match, it will loop for nothing right, are you not looking to ask to guess again?

Comment: [codecademy](https://www.codecademy.com) is a nice tutorial site with interactive shell style lessons. The python 3 course is for Pro subscribers that you can try for free. It will really take you step by step from the basics which is important. I'm sure there are alot more sites similar to that

Comment: @NicLaforge trying to get it to ask again until number is guessed then quit

Comment: For loop is not the right one here. Try to use a ```while True``` loop. Keep your if/else and exit only on success, include the ```input``` in that loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will try to cover a few issues in your code and then suggest an alternative:

### 1. `for guess in hidden`:

this has two issues: First you are overriding the `guess` variable that you just used to get input from the user. Second you are trying to iterate through `hidden` which is the number you got from `rand`. Numbers can't be iterated over, only "iterables" (lists, sets, dictionaries etc...).

### 2. `print("That\'s it!\n\n Congrats !") + quit()`

I am guessing here that you are referring to the `+` operator like the `;` in C. A way to concatenate commands. Well it don't work that way in python. Each command goes in its own line.

Finally you probably wanted something like:

```py
hidden = random.randrange(1, 100)
print(hidden)

guess = int(input("Please enter your guess: "))

while guess != hidden:
    if guess < hidden:
        print("Too low :(")
    else:
        print("Too high!")
    guess = int(input("Please try again: "))

print("That\'s it!\n\n Congrats !")
```

Here we are taking the first guess from the user. And then, `while` it is **not** equal to the `hidden` number, we will keep asking the user for another input while giving him the hints. Then, when he finally hits the number, the loop will exit (because now the condition fails) and our success message will print and the program will terminate.

Comment: That makes a lot more sense, thanks. In what situation would it be appropriate to use a `for` statement?

Comment: `for` loops (generally applies in any programming language) are more suitable when you have a known sized element to go over. For example iterating over a list. `while` loops are more suitable when you don't have a specific boundary, like here that we want to keep asking until the user gets it right. we can't know how many times that would be! with `while` loops you should always be careful not to get an infinite loop. like: `while True: print("hi")` that will run forever.

Comment: Thank you for the extra feed back! This is kinda the type of thing I'm looking for. I understand things so much better when I can ask specific questions.